# Limit ScrolledComposite to painting just the visible area on resize

Tags: java, swt

I have a ScrolledComposite which contains some custom composites which are used as containers for a few Label objects and a profile picture about that text (Imagine that like an email client with many emails in the incoming box). The problem is, if that ScrolledComposite has a few hundred of those composites, resizing of the ScrolledComposite (via Tracker or Window resizing) takes too long (more than a second) since the whole composites in the ScrolledComposite must also be resized. Is there any way to improve the performance maybe by using a cache? or just resizing the composites which are visible to user? Is there anyone out there who faced the same problem?

I appreciate any help. Ty.

Comment: ``org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SharedScrolledComposite` has some size caching, you might be able to adapt that.

Comment: hey, ty for your reply. I'm gonna have a look at the source code.